# JQuery .hover has memory

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following simple code to make a drop down menu:

```
jQuery("#navigation li").hover(
    function(){jQuery(this).children("ul").slideToggle("fast");}, 
    function(){jQuery(this).children("ul").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

However when I hover the `#naviagtion li` multiple times really quick, it will keep slideToggling the same amount of times. How do you stop that from doing it.

I was messing around with some sort of flags (`isSliding`) in the code to see if it's currently toggling but it seemed really buggy when I used it. (i set the flag before it started sliding and in the callback I set the flag to false again. And before I called the function i just had an `if(isSliding)` statement.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8KxCd/2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use .stop()

http://jsfiddle.net/genesis/8KxCd/4/

```
jQuery("#navigation li").hover(

function() {

    jQuery(this).children("ul").stop(true, true).slideToggle("fast");
}, function() {
    jQuery(this).children("ul").stop(true, true).slideToggle("fast");

});
```

Comment: Awesome very clean simple solution :D

Comment: Heh no xD I couldn't because you were so super fast!